# How to get UID of mail in All Maill folder if I have UID of this mail in inbox using imaplib? (GMail)

Tags: python, gmail, imaplib

How to get UID of mail in All Maill folder if I have UID of this mail in inbox using imaplib?
As you know the google store mails in the two instances in All Mail and in inbox I whant to move this to mail in trash folder using imaplib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using any of the 2 following ways.

1. You can use `Message-Id` field of the mail header.`Message-Id` field for both the mail 
       will be same.
2. Apply `SEARCH`  command on `All Mail` Folder.
      i.e search on title --> it will give you `uid` for that mail.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by searching with X-GM-MSGID  over  ALLMail folder.

Message X-GM-MSGID is unique across all folders in Gmail. So You just need to fetch X-GM-MSGID of  email in INBOX along with UID.

Now  You need to search with X-GM-MSGID on AllMail folder  like this

UID SEARCH X-GM-MSGID 1278455344230334865

You can find more details here
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions#access_to_the_gmail_unique_message_id_x-gm-msgid

I don't think imap lib supports Gmail enhanched capabulities.
You may need to extend the imap library with the Gmail specific commands.